# Display complete list of categories and subcategories using Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, nested-repeater

I have successfully displayed the list of categories and their corresponding sub categories using nested Repeater controls:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rMainCategories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rMainCategories_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryName" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("MainCategory") %>' />
        </li>
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rSubCategories" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubCategory")%>' />
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
void GetCategories()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT m.MainCatID, m.Category AS MainCategory " +
        "FROM MainCategories m WHERE m.MainCatID " +
        "IN (SELECT MainCatID FROM SubCategories) " +
        "SELECT s.SubCatID, s.Category AS SubCategory, s.MainCatID FROM SubCategories s";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("CategoriesRelation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["MainCatID"],
        ds.Tables[1].Columns["MainCatID"]));
    rMainCategories.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    rMainCategories.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void rMainCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        Repeater rSubCategories = e.Item.FindControl("rSubCategories") as Repeater;
        rSubCategories.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("CategoriesRelation");
        rSubCategories.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: list of main categories with sub categories]

**List of Main Categories**

[image: list of main categories]

Is there a way I can also display categories without sub categories?
Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: do you want do display categories which doesn't have subcategories???

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Yes. The complete list of categories.

Answer (score 1):

```
I Think I Had Done In Some Different Way I Think You Can Like My Answer
See My Code:
Tables
[Category][1][Products][2]


[Sub Category][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib6yc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyXap.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVZh.png
My Aspx code In Nested Repeater
                         <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ReptrOuter" OnItemDataBound="ReptrOuter_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ReptrOuter_ItemCommand">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>  

                                            <ul class="main-navigation js-main-nav"><!--All Opening-->
                                                 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="Category.aspx">Products</a><!--main Nav closing-->
                                                     <ul class="sub-menu"><!--childerns Opening-->
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><!--Category open-->
                                                       <asp:LinkButton ID="LBCategory" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CategoryID")%>' Text='<%#Eval("CategoryName")%>'></asp:LinkButton>


                                                       <asp:Label ID="LBLCategoryID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CategoryID")%>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>

                                            <asp:Repeater ID="ReptrMiddle" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ReptrMiddle_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ReptrMiddle_ItemCommand">
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                      <ul class="sub-menu menu-item-has-children"><!--Sub UnlistedCategory open-->
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><!--Name Of Sub Category-->

                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LBSubCategory" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CategoryID")+","+Eval("SubCategoryID")%>' Text='<%#Eval("SubCategoryName")%>' OnClick="LBSubCategory_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

                                                       <asp:Label ID="LBLSubCategoryID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SubCategoryID")%>' Visible="false"> </asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ReptrInner" OnItemCommand="ReptrInner_ItemCommand">
                                                      <HeaderTemplate>
                                                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                      </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LBProduct" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CategoryID")+","+Eval("SubCategoryID")+","+Eval("ProductID")%>' Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                        </li>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                         </ul><!--Sub UnlistedCategory Close-->
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>

                                               </li><!--Category Closing-->
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            </ul><!--childerns closing-->
                                            </li><!--main Nav closing-->
                                             </ul><!--All Closing-->
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
C# Code For All
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JEETANWebApp
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {

               // _Product p = new _Product();
               // _SubCategory sb = new _SubCategory();

                ////bindProducts();
               // bindCateory();
            }
            else
            {
                _Category c = new _Category();
                bindCateory();
            }
        }
        //    public void bindProducts()
        //    {
        //    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        //    {
        //        con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
        //        con.Open();
        //        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_Product", con))
        //        {
        //            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ReadAll";
        //            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        //            {
        //                if (dr.HasRows)
        //                {
        //                    List<_Product> products = new List<_Product>();
        //                    while (dr.Read())
        //                    {
        //                        _Product p = new _Product();
        //                        p.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]);
        //                        p.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SubCategoryID"]);
        //                        p.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"]);
        //                        p.ProductName = Convert.ToString(dr["ProductName"]);
        //                        p.Description = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"]);
        //                        p.DExtension = Convert.ToString(dr["DExtension"]);
        //                        p.IImageID = Convert.ToString(dr["IImageID"]);
        //                        p.DImageID = Convert.ToString(dr["DImageID"]);
        //                        p.IExtension = Convert.ToString(dr["IExtension"]);
        //                        products.Add(p);
        //                    }
        //                   List<_Product> pr = products.OrderBy(ps => ps.ProductID).ToList();
        //                    products = new List<_Product>(pr);
        //                   // LsVwHome.DataSource = products;
        //                   // LsVwHome.DataBind();

        //                }
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }

        //}
        public void bindCateory()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_Category", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ReadAll";
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            List<_Category> categories = new List<_Category>();
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                _Category c = new _Category();
                                c.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]);
                                c.CategoryName = Convert.ToString(dr["CategoryName"]);
                                c.Description = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"]);
                                    categories.Add(c);
                            }
                            List<_Category> ct = categories.OrderBy(cis => cis.CategoryID).ToList();
                            categories = new List<_Category>(ct);
                            ReptrOuter.DataSource =categories;
                            ReptrOuter.DataBind();
                            //List<_Product> pr = products.OrderBy(ps => ps.ProductID).ToList();
                            //products = new List<_Product>(pr);
                            // LsVwHome.DataSource = products;
                            // LsVwHome.DataBind();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        protected void ReptrOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {


            if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item||e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item)
            {
                Label lb = new Label();
                lb = e.Item.FindControl("LBLCategoryID") as Label;
                //int id = Convert.ToInt32(lb.Text);
                ViewState["CatID"] = Convert.ToInt32(lb.Text);
                DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
                Repeater ReptrMiddle = e.Item.FindControl("ReptrMiddle") as Repeater;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_SubCategory", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SubRead";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ViewState["CatID"];
                        //cmd.Parameters.Add();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (dr.HasRows)
                            {
                                List<_SubCategory> subCategories = new List<_SubCategory>();
                                while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    _SubCategory SC = new _SubCategory();
                                    SC.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]);
                                    SC.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SubCategoryID"]);
                                    SC.SubCategoryName = Convert.ToString(dr["SubCategoryName"]);
                                    subCategories.Add(SC);
                                }
                                ReptrMiddle.DataSource = subCategories;
                                ReptrMiddle.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        protected void ReptrMiddle_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                Label Sublb = new Label();
                Sublb = e.Item.FindControl("LBLSubCategoryID") as Label;
                int Subid = Convert.ToInt32(Sublb.Text);
                DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
                Repeater ReptrInner = e.Item.FindControl("ReptrInner") as Repeater;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_Product", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ReadWithCatSubCat";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ViewState["CatID"];
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubCategoryID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Subid;
                        //cmd.Parameters.Add();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (dr.HasRows)
                            {
                                List<_Product> products = new List<_Product>();
                                while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    _Product product = new _Product();
                                    product.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"]);
                                    product.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SubCategoryID"]);
                                    product.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ProductID"]);
                                    product.ProductName = Convert.ToString(dr["ProductName"]);
                                    products.Add(product);
                                }
                                ReptrInner.DataSource = products;
                                ReptrInner.DataBind();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        protected void ReptrOuter_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CategoryID"] = e.CommandArgument;
            Response.Redirect("SubCategory.aspx");
        }

        protected void LBSubCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ReptrMiddle_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] values = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Session["CategoryID"] = values[0];
            Session["SubCategoryID"] = values[1];
            Response.Redirect("Products.aspx");
        }

        protected void ReptrInner_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] values = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Session["CategoryID"] = values[0];
            Session["SubCategoryID"] = values[1];
            Session["ProductID"] = values[2];
            Response.Redirect("Product.aspx");
        }
    }

    public class _Product
    {
        public int ProductID {get;set;}  
        public string ProductName {get;set;}
        public int SubCategoryID {get;set;}
        public string Description {get;set;}
        public int CategoryID {get;set;}
        public string Drawing { get; set; }
        public string DExtension { get; set; }
        public string IImageID {get;set;}
        public string DImageID { get; set; }
        public string IExtension { get; set; }
    }
    public class _SubCategory
    {
            public int SubCategoryID {get;set;}
            public string SubCategoryName {get;set;}
            public int CategoryID {get;set;}
            public string Description {get;set;}

    }
    public class _Category
    {
        public int CategoryID   {get;set;}
        public string CategoryName {get;set;}
        public string Description  {get;set;}

    }
}
Store Procedures
USP_Category:
USE [JEETANVALVEDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_Category]    Script Date: 11-Aug-18 1:00:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[USP_Category]
@Action varchar(30)=null,
@CategoryID int=null,
@CategoryName varchar(100)=null,
@Description  varchar(500)=null,
@CreatedBy tinyint=null,
@ModifiedBy  tinyint=null,
@Image  varchar(50)=null,
@Extension  varchar(10)=null
as
begin
    if @Action='Create'
    begin
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Category]([CategoryName],[Description],[IsActive],[CreatedBy],
            [ModifiedBy],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[Extension])
        VALUES(@CategoryName,@Description,1,@CreatedBy,null,GETDATE(),null,@Extension);
        update [dbo].[Category]
                set [Image]=Concat('C', @@IDENTITY)
                where dbo.Category.CategoryID=@@IDENTITY;
                select CONCAT('C',@@IDENTITY) as Message;
    end
    if @Action='Read'
    begin
        select CategoryID,CategoryName,Description,IsActive,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,CreatedDate,ModifiedDate from Category where CategoryID=@CategoryID;
    end
    if @Action='ReadAll'
    begin
        select CategoryID,CategoryName,[Description],IsActive,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,CreatedDate,ModifiedDate,Image,Extension from Category;
    end
    if @Action='Update'
    begin
        if @CategoryID is not null
        begin
            if @Extension is null
            begin 
                UPDATE [dbo].[Category]
               SET [CategoryName] = ISNULL(@CategoryName, CategoryName)
                    ,[Description] = ISNULL(@Description,[Description])
                    ,[ModifiedDate] = GETDATE()
                    ,[ModifiedBy] =@ModifiedBy
                    WHERE CategoryID=@CategoryID;
                select 'Sucess' as Message;
            end
            else
            begin
                UPDATE [dbo].[Category]
               SET [CategoryName] = ISNULL(@CategoryName,CategoryName)
                    ,[Description] = ISNULL(@Description,[Description])
                    ,[ModifiedDate] = GETDATE()
                    ,[ModifiedBy] =@ModifiedBy
                    ,[Extension] = @Extension
                    WHERE CategoryID=@CategoryID;
                SELECT [Image] as Message from Category where CategoryID=@CategoryID;
            end
        end
        else
        begin
            select 'Id Is Required' As Message;
        end
    end
end
USP_SUBCategory
USE [JEETANVALVEDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_SubCategory]    Script Date: 10-Aug-18 6:26:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[USP_SubCategory]
@Action varchar(30)=null,
@CategoryID int=null,
@SubCategoryID int=null
as
begin
    if @Action='ReadAll'
    begin
        SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName, CategoryID, Description,Image,Extension, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate
        FROM SubCategory ;
    end
    if @Action='Read'
    begin
        SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName, CategoryID, Description,Image,Extension, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate
        FROM SubCategory where SubCategoryID=@SubCategoryID and CategoryID=@CategoryID ;
    end
    if @Action='ReadWithCategory'
    begin
        SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName, CategoryID, Description,Image,Extension, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate
        FROM SubCategory where  CategoryID=@CategoryID ;
    end
    if @Action='SubRead'
    begin
        SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName,CategoryID FROM SubCategory where  CategoryID=@CategoryID ;
    end
end
USP_Products:
USE [JEETANVALVEDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_Product ]    Script Date: 10-Aug-18 7:23:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Batch submitted through debugger: SQLQuery2.sql|7|0|C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs304F.sql
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[USP_Product ]
@Action varchar(30)=null,
@ProductID int=null,
@ProductName Varchar(100)=null,
@CategoryID int=null,
@SubCategoryID int=null,
@Description varchar(500)=null,
@IImageID varchar(50)=null,
@DImageID varchar(50)=null,
@IExtension varchar(10)=null,
@DExtension varchar(10)=null,
@CreatedBy int=null,
@ModifiedBy int=null,
@CreatedDate date=null,
@ModifiedDate date=null
as
begin
    if @Action='Create'
    begin
        --begin try
        --  begin transaction
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName]
                ,[SubCategoryID],[Description],[CategoryID],[IsActive],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedBy],[CreatedDate]
                ,[ModifiedDate],[IImageID],[IExtension],[DImageID],[DExtension] )VALUES(@ProductName,@SubCategoryID,@Description,@CategoryID,
                1,@CreatedBy,@ModifiedBy,GETDATE(),null,@IImageID,@IExtension,@DImageID,@DExtension);
                update [dbo].[Product]
                set IImageID=@CategoryID+@SubCategoryID+@@IDENTITY
                where dbo.Product.ProductID=@@IDENTITY;
                select CONCAT(@CategoryID,@SubCategoryID,@@IDENTITY) as Message;
        --  commit transaction;
        --end try
        --begin catch
        --  rollback transaction
        --  select 'Error' as Message;
        --end catch

    end 
    if @Action='Read'
    begin
        SELECT [ProductID],[SubCategoryID],[CategoryID],[ProductName],[Description],[CreatedBy]
        ,[ModifiedBy],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[IImageID],[IExtension],[DImageID],[DExtension]
        FROM Product where ProductID=@ProductID and SubCategoryID=@SubCategoryID and CategoryID=@CategoryID;
    end
    if @Action='ReadAll'
    begin
        SELECT [ProductID],[SubCategoryID],[CategoryID],[ProductName],[Description],[CreatedBy]
        ,[ModifiedBy],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[IImageID],[IExtension],[DImageID],[DExtension]
        FROM [dbo].[Product];
    end
    if @Action='ReadWithCatSubCat'
    begin
            SELECT [ProductID],[SubCategoryID],[CategoryID],[ProductName],[Description],[CreatedBy]
        ,[ModifiedBy],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[IImageID],[IExtension],[DImageID],[DExtension]
        FROM [dbo].[Product] where SubCategoryID=@SubCategoryID and CategoryID=@CategoryID;
    end
    --if @Action='Update' 
    --begin
    --  select null;
    --end
    if @Action='Delete' 
    begin
        select null;
    end
    --if @Action='Activate'
    --begin
    --  select null;
    --end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

I will Suggest You Bind Your Main Categories to
 Repeater in this method `GetCategories()`

```
public Void GetCategories()
{
rMainCategories.datasource=dt ;      // select * from MainCategories
rMainCategories.DataBind();

}
```

Fetch Data Like and Save in `Session[subcategory]`

```
select * from subcategories where MainCatid in 
(select MainCad ID from Categories)
```

And In DataBound Method Bind Your Subcategories

```
protected void rMainCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        Repeater rSubCategories = e.Item.FindControl("rSubCategories") as Repeater;
        // save MainCatID in rMainCategories
        Label lblMainCatID=(Label)e.Item.FindControl(lblMainCatID);

     DataTable subcat=(DataTable)Session[subcategory];

    rSubCategories.DataSource = dt;        // filter subcate with MainCatID 
    rSubCategories.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: I want to display list of main categories (with or without subcategories)

Comment: @abramlimpin Please Show some samples and Expected Output